# how get value of a expression in another one in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng

I am trying to take value of one expression to another as below:

```
<label  class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="a in filters"> {{a.label}}
            <select ng-model="qqq">
                <option ng-repeat="f in values " ng-value="{{f.{{a.label}}}}" >
                 {{f.{{a.label}}}}
                </option>
            </select>
 </label>
```

I know that not the correct way but just to explain the question exactly I wrote that. Also both Values and filters are two different and independent json objects, So suppose if

```
{{a.label}}= manufacture
```

then

```
{{f.{{a.label}}}} = {{f.manufacture}}
```

and both the object doesn't have any common attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property like `{{f[a.label]}}`.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Please, provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it will give more context. "That doesn't work" says nothing about the problem you are facing.